# How to fix ‘amp-img Not Displaying image In Gmail'

Tags: amp-html, amp-email

Gmail cuts out the image tag and inserts the tag

```html
<u></u>
<u></u>
```

instead of graphics

my code:

```html
<amp-img src="https://img_url/1.gif" height="142" width="250" alt="an image"></amp-img>
```

HEAD looks like that:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html ⚡4email>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script async src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0.js"></script>
  <style amp4email-boilerplate>body{visibility:hidden}</style>
```

the code is correct i tested 
https://playground.amp.dev (AMP for Email)

code:
https://pastebin.com/65LeQxk1

Comment: Please link to the code

Comment: Your email seems to work fine when I send it via amp.gmail.dev. How are you testing it?